# Magento webservice api expose blocks

Tags: magento

We would like to expose some Magento blocks through the webservice API like Magebridge does. Actually Magebridge does exactly what we want but this is too tightly integrated with Joomla to re-use for another CMS.

Thanks!
Jasper

Comment: Sort of a vague question. Specifics usually get you a quicker answer.

Answer (score 1):

I used [this article](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/custom-api) a few years ago to expose a few custom web service APIs.  Between that and the MageBridge code you should have enough example code to get started.